# Add < to Html text to display in a browser

Tags: html

I want to create a tag:

```
   <div id="Id_Field" class="myclass"> <<Nack>> </div>
```

So the browser will display:

```
<<Nack>>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use the HTML entities: `&gt;` and `&lt;`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTML_entities#Character_entity_references_in_HTML

Answer (score 1):

Use the character reference `&gt;` to represent a < character as data (as opposed to the start of a tag).

Answer (score 0):

use &lt; and &gt; for < and >, respectively

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="Id_Field" class="myclass"> &lt;&lt;Nack&gt;&gt; </div>
```

The above ASCII code will convert to less-than and greater-than symbols when viewing in the browser.